# Convert UInt32 to float without rounding?

Tags: c#-4.0, floating-point, rounding, floating-point-precision

I need to convert a UInt32 type to a float without having it rounded.  Say I do

```
float num = 4278190335;
uint num1 = num;
```

The value instantly gets changed to 4278190336.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: The code you've provided does the opposite conversion from the one you mention *and* it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: The conversion of UInt32 to float is done in the first line.

Comment: That's a compile-time conversion though... and if you're not going to have any execution-time conversions, why have the second line?

Answer (score 9):

> I need to convert a UInt32 type to a float without having it rounded.

That can't be done.

There are 2<sup>32</sup> possible `uint` values. There are fewer than 2<sup>32</sup> `float` values (there are 2<sup>32</sup> bit patterns, but that includes various NaN values). Add to that the fact that there are obviously a lot of `float` values which can't be represented as `uint` (e.g. 0.5) and it becomes clear that you can't represent every `uint` value exactly in a `float`. However, every `uint` (and every `int`) *can* be represented exactly as a `double`, so that might be a solution to your problem.

The problem you're seeing in your original source code is that 4278190335 isn't exactly representable as a `float`; the closest `float` value is 4278190336. This isn't a problem with the conversion from `float` to `uint` - it's a problem with the conversion from the exact value you've specified in your source code into a `float`; the `float` to `uint` conversion happens separately (and again, can easily lose information).

Comment: As a side note: 4278190335 can be represented as a `double` if the data type `double` can be used instead of `float`.

Comment: @grovesNL: Indeed, every `uint` can be represented in `double`. I thought I'd included that in my answer, but apparently not. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

`float` has only 23 bits of mantissa. Along with the implicit 1 bit it can only represent exactly all numbers that fit in 24 bits. For numbers larger than that it can only store the ***nearest*** value. 4278190335 = 0xFF0000FF > 2<sup>24</sup> so it'll be rounded to 4278190336 when converting to float

Similarly `double` has 52 bits of mantissa and can represent all numbers within the range [-2<sup>53</sup>, 2<sup>53</sup>] exactly, so it can store any value that fit in 32-bit int including 4278190335. But again double can't store all numbers in `long`'s range although they have the same size (64 bits)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your question being worded backward; I think what you are saying is.

You need to get the integer portion of a float value, e.g. its whole number value not its decimal value. In which case you can simply cast the float to an int, casting does not round.
e.g.

```
float myFloat = 1.5;
uint myInt = (uint)myFloat; //myInt == 1
```

Keep in mind though this isn't always clear to others reading your code. To help there Math.Floor and Math.Ceiling ... Floor returns the whole number below the current value, ceiling returns the whole number above it
e.g

```
float myFloat = 1.5;
uint myFloorInt = (uint)Math.Floor(myFloat); //myFloorInt == 1
uint myCeilingInt = (uint)Math.Ceiling(myFloat); //myCeilingInt == 2
```

You will need to cast or convert the value from float to uint, int, etc. as your needs dictate. Most frown on casting as the resulting value isn't always clear to people ... Convert has various methods to help you convert one value to another in nice clearly understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to turn back the original value in your method.
i suggest to try byte to byte copying to make it posible retrieving data back. float typecasting could change original value.
if your processor is 32bit it could help u:

```
uint32 x;
float y;
memcpy((uint8*)&y,(uint8*)&x,4);
```

(mohandes...)

Comment: The question is about C# and not c++.